# Angular formControl not showing mat-error upon making validation

Tags: angular, validation

I'm using Angular and I'm making a FormGroup which contains a FormArray which contains a FormGroup which contains a FormControl. When clicking the submit button, I want to validate all my fields before making an action.

When you click the submit button, all filed with error will become red, but the mat-error component will stay hidden and that is my problem. I would like to know how I could update my code so that mat-error respond as expected.

Here's an example of my code:

my.component.ts:

```js
export class myComponent implements OnInit {

  public optionList = [{
    value: 1
    name: option1
  }, {
    value: 2
    name: option2
  }, {
    value: 3
    name: option3
  }];

  public myFormArray: FormArray = new FormArray([]);
  public myFormGroup: FormGroup;

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.myFormGroup = new FormGroup({
      myFormArray: this.myFormArray
    });
    this.myFormArray.push(
      new FormGroup({
        myFormControl: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
      })
    );
  }

  public validateAllFields(formGroup: FormGroup): void {
    Object.keys(formGroup.controls).forEach(field => {
      const control = formGroup.get(field);
      if (control instanceof FormControl) {
        control.markAsTouched({ onlySelf: true });
      } else if (control instanceof FormGroup) {
        this.validateAllFields(control);
      }
    });
  }

  public validateOneField(formControl: FormControl): boolean {
    return formControl.invalid && (formControl.dirty || formControl.touched);
  }

}
```

my.component.html

```html
<div [formGroup]="myFormGroup">
  <div *ngFor="let myItem of myFormArray.controls">
    <ng-container [formGroup]="myItem">
      <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>Choose</mat-label>
        <mat-select formControlName="myFormControl">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let opt of optionList" [value]="opt.value">{{opt.name}}</mat-option>
        </mat-select>
        <mat-error *ngIf="validateOneField(opt.controls.myFormControl)">
          My Error Message!!!
        </mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>
    </ng-container>
  </div>
</div>
<button (click)="validateAllFields(myFormGroup)">Submit</button>
```

Comment: you needn't use *ngIf="validateOneField(...), mat-error, by defect only show the error if the control is touched and invalid -you can change this behaivor, see https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview#changing-when-error-messages-are-shown. Anyway, you has a type error, I suppose you want to say `validateOneField(myItem.get('myFormControl'))` -or `validateOneFiled(myItem.controls.myFormControl)` , I'm not prety sure this last one -but sure is not **opt**

Comment: Thanks for this. I removed all the *ngIf and made my custom state matcher, wich fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem by creating my own error state matcher.

custom-error.state-matcher.ts:

```js
import { ErrorStateMatcher } from '@angular/material/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroupDirective, NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

export class CustomErrorStateMatcher implements ErrorStateMatcher {
  isErrorState(control: FormControl | null, form: FormGroupDirective | NgForm | null): boolean {
    const isSubmitted = form && form.submitted;
    return !!(control && control.invalid && (control.dirty || control.touched || isSubmitted));
  }
}
```

After the creation of your custom state matcher, you'll need to add the followingline in your component to activate it.

my.component.ts:

```js
public matcher = new CustomErrorStateMatcher();
```

When it's done, you can remove all the *ngIf="" used for validation.

Shoutout to @Eliseo for the input!